# C++ possible coin combinations using while loop

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop

I have a challenge in my programming class where we have to use a void function to calculate the possible coin combinations with a given change value from 1 to 99 cents.

So far my code looks like this:

```
    #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void computeCoins(int coinValue, int& num, int& amount_left);

int main()
{
    //Define varibles then get user input for change
    int leftOver, quarters=0, dimes=0, nickels=0, pennies=0, coins=0, originalAmount;
    do
    {
    cout << "Enter change amount: ";
    cin >> originalAmount;
    leftOver = originalAmount;
    } while ((leftOver > 99) || (leftOver < 1)); //Larger than 99 or smaller than 1? If yes, then try again.

    //Quarters
    computeCoins(25, coins, leftOver);
    quarters = coins;

    //Dimes
    computeCoins(10, coins, leftOver);
    dimes = coins;

    //Nickels
    computeCoins(5, coins, leftOver);
    nickels = coins;
    pennies = leftOver;

    cout << originalAmount << " cent/s could be given as " << quarters << " quarter/s, " << dimes << " dime/s, " << nickels << " nickel/s, " << " and " << pennies << " pennies.";
    cout << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

void computeCoins(int coinValue, int& num, int& amount_left)
{
    //Using the specified coin value, find how many can go into it then subtract it
    while (amount_left % coinValue == 0)
    {
        // Still dividable by the coin value
        num += 1;
        amount_left -= coinValue;
    }
}
```

Now my problem is when I run the program, it returns a very large negative value for quarters, dimes, and nickels. I'm positive it has something to do with how my loop conditions are set up, does anyone have an idea why this is happening?

Comment: Have you tried debugging into your program and stepping through it to see what it is actually doing?

Comment: you haven't initialized `coins` . So it might be using a garbage value.

Comment: I've used several breakpoints while debugging, from what I've seen in the loop, it seems to be calculating the modular division correctly.

Comment: @Vandesh: it's more serious than that: actually UB.

Comment: Shouldn't you be doing `while (amount_left/coin_value>0)`. Also, if I read the problem correctly, it asks how many ways are there to get the total value. You seem to be looking for the simplest one.

Comment: @Vandesh Caught that, that fixed the large negative values being printed, however it will now only print 0 for those values. Is there something I'm missing in the function itself? I figured using references would be the easiest way to do this.

Comment: can you update the latest code again in your original post?

Comment: also, from the looks of your code, do you mean *optimal* possible coin combinations ?

Comment: How to debug your program: http://www.drpaulcarter.com/cs/debug.php

Comment: Thanks for the replys everyone, completely forgot that integer division rounded down in the first place. Thanks a ton! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two issues: one undefined coins initial value. Two the `amount_left % coinValue == 0` part - I think you mean `amount_left >= coinValue`

Although there is no need to keep iterating in that function

```
void computeCoins(int coinValue, int& num, int& amount_left)
{
    // add as many coinValues as possible.    
    num += amount_left / coinValue;
    // the modulus must be what is left.
    amount_left = amount_left % coinValue;
}
```

Note that (among other things), you'd be better off using `unsigned ints` for quantities of things.

Comment: Never mind, that actually fixed it. I should really think more "Occam's Razor" from now on.

Comment: Not required - since you are dividing integers, the C standard says the result will always round towards 0.

Comment: Since you need to calculate the number of each type of coin, rather than the toal number of all coins, that `num +=` should just be `num =`.

Comment: depends. This way fits the original code and can be used for either approach (just reset / stash num between calls)

Answer (score 0):

As I read your question, it appears you are supposed to look for a way to get all possible combinations.  Oliver Matthews' answer handles the first part of that (figuring out how many of a given type of coin you can fit in the change), but you'd have to do that in a loop that checks various other combinations (e.g. all pennies, all nickels w/pennies, all dimes w/pennies, all quarters w/pennies, etc.) and need a method for returning the combinations (e.g. return a vector of some structure/class that handles the coin counts through an output parameter - that is, a vector by reference).